# Kotlin Firebase don't update children

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, kotlin

Let us consider a store which has a name and then collections which is an array of collection

```
store 
   -- name
   -- id
   -- collections

collection
   -- name
   -- id
   -- other nested items
```

I have stored data in the same structure in firebase and also there is a corresponding kotlin data class.

When I create a firebase reference to store and then push changes to it, I assume that it is going to create a huge JSON blob which also has the data for the collections and then send it.

What I want to avoid is sending the huge blob. I want to only partially update the name and id and not the collections.

I tried using a combination of `@Exclude` on `set` and `get` so that we can fetch the collections but not send it to firebase database but no luck.

```
    // Restricting only firebase writes to collections, not reads
    @Exclude @set: Exclude var collections: List<Collections>? = null
```

Any way we can send updates to an object but not its children?

Edit I am working on Android Using the RealTime database.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you talking about Realtime Database or Cloud Firestore?  Are you working on Android or using the Firebase Admin SDK?  What is the code you're working with that doesn't work the way you expect?  Please edit your question to include these details.

Comment: @DougStevenson done!

Comment: If you only want to update a couple children, the just build a Map with those child names and values and pass that to the SDK.  It'll be far easier than trying to do static excludes.

Comment: It seems you are trying to do an [Android RTDB Update Operation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data). But you need to **omit** the collections key from your update operation. If you include it as a null value, you will delete the data at collections.